# share image doesn't refresh

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

share image doesn't refresh on pravoved.ru

We have changed all the pictures, for example og:image attribute picture about a week ago, but it doesn't refresh, so if you click facebook share link in the footer, you will see still croped picture. How to change it? I've tried everything. For example, using of this service https://developers.facebook.com, and i have pasted such a javascript code "&p[images][0]=" + "http://pravoved.ru/images/pravoved-avatar.jpg"
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> you will see still croped picture

That *is* your actual og:image http://pravoved.ru/images/pravoved-avatar.jpg, but as you said, it gets cropped by Facebook.

In the share dialog, when you inspect the preview image, you can see its URL is

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAtXVeqx7Q9IPa8&w=100&h=100&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpravoved.ru%2Fimages%2Fpravoved-avatar.jpg&cfs=1&upscale

– so you can clearly see that the value of the `url` parameter is what you want it to be.

If you [change the last parameter of that URL to upscale=0](https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAtXVeqx7Q9IPa8&w=100&h=100&url=http://pravoved.ru/images/pravoved-avatar.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=0), you can see it is exactly your image (cropped to square). (You can’t do that in the dialog, of course – I’m mentioning it just to prove the point.)

Your original image is only 100 x 103 pixels big, whereas Facebook recommends using images that are *at least* 200 x 200 pixels. So swap your image for a bigger one, and ideally totally square. Facebook says 600 x 600 px is good (for retina displays on mobile), and they even say somewhere that if you have an image of 1500 x 1500 pixels you should feel free to use it, “the bigger the better” (within reasonable limits, of course).

Comment: I'll try to make it bigger and report to you. Thanks.

Comment: I've made bigger picture (200x200) and uploaded it to test stand prerelease.pravoved.com.ru, but it is still cropped the same. https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAtXVeqx7Q9IPa8&w=100&h=100&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpravoved.ru%2Fimages%2Fpravoved-avatar.jpg&cfs=1&upscale

What should I do to make it right? Maybe I must resize logo at the picture, move it more inside the square?

Comment: That’s because on your preprelease page your share dialog still points to the same old URL … [use the right URL](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fprerelease.pravoved.com.ru), and you’ll see it shows a non-cropped picture …

Comment: Our picture is right now at http://pravoved.ru/images/pravoved-avatar.jpg but if I use your right URL https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpravoved.ru you can still see cropped picture. Why is it cropped?